# Regex to MATCH number string (with optional text) in a sentence

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I am trying to write a regex that matches only strings like this:

```
89-72 
10-123
109-12
122-311(a)
22-311(a)(1)(d)(4)
```

These strings are embedded in sentences and sometimes there are 2 potential matches in the sentence like this:

> In section **10-123** which references section **122-311(a)** there is a phone number 456-234-2222

I do not want to match the phone.  Here is my current working regex

```
\d{2,3}\-\d{2,3}(\([a-zA-Z0-9]\))*
```

see [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yjRSll/4)

I've been looking on Stack and have not found anything yet. Any help would be appreciated.  Will be using this in a google sheet and potentially postgres.

Comment: I have an idea: 1) `\b(\d{2,3}-\d{2,3}\b(?:\([A-Za-z0-9]\))*)(?:[^-]|$)` (Google Spreadsheets) and 2) `\y\d{2,3}-\d{2,3}\y(?:\([A-Za-z0-9]\))*(?!-)` (PostgreSQL). Note there may be problems with extracting multiple occurrences in Google Spreadsheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on regex, suggested by @Wiktor Stribiżew:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,REPT("\b(\d{2,3}-\d{2,3}\b(?:\([A-Za-z0-9]\))*)(?:[^-]|$)(?:.*)",LEN(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\b(\d{2,3}-\d{2,3}\b(?:\([A-Za-z0-9]\))*)(?:[^-]|$)", char (9)),"[^"&char(9)&"]",""))))
```

The formula will return all matches.

String:

```
A

In 22-311(a)(1)(d)(4) section 10-123 which ... 122-311(a) ... number 456-234-2222
```

Output:

```
B                   C       D                  

22-311(a)(1)(d)(4)  10-123  122-311(a)
```

## Solution

To extract all matches from a string, use this pattern:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,
  REPT(basic_regex & "(?:.*)",
  LEN(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1,basic_regex, char (9)),"[^"&char(9)&"]",""))))`

The tail of a function:

`LEN(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1,basic_regex, char (9)),"[^"&char(9)&"]","")))`

is just for finding number 3 -- how many entries of a pattern in a string.

Answer (score 2):

To not match the phone number you have to indicate that the match must neither be preceded nor followed by \d or -. Google spreadsheet uses RE2 which does not support look around assertion (see [the list of supported feature](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt)) so as far as I can tell, the only solution is to add a character before and after the match, or the string boundary:

```
(?:^|[^-\d])\d{2,3}\-\d{2,3}(\([a-zA-Z0-9]\))*(?:$|[^-\d])
```

`(?:^|[^-\d])` means either the start of a line (`^`) or a character that is not - or \d (you might want to change that, and forbid all letters as well). `$` is the end of a line. `^` and `$` only do what you want with the `/m` flag though

As you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/yjRSll/5) this finds the correct strings, but with additional spaces around some of the matches.